# Don't understand Derivation step using Normal Distribution CDF

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

I'm working on Deriving the characteristic function for the maximum of a drifted brownian motion $W(t) + at$, I've found a paper deriving what I need, but I don't understand the following step they make (without explanation):

$$
\begin{aligned}
g(y) &= -\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{1}{T^{3/2}}e^{2ya}\bigg[\int_{-\infty}^y[x-(2y+Ta)]e^{-[x-(2y+Ta)]^2/2T}dx + Ta\int_{-\infty}^ye^{-[x-(2y+Ta)]^2/2T}dx\bigg]\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{T\pi}}e^{2ya}\bigg[e^{-(y+Ta)^2/2T} - a\sqrt{2\pi T}\,\Phi\left(\frac{-y-Ta}{\sqrt{T}}\right)\bigg]
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\Phi$ is the cdf for the standard normal distribution
$$
\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-t^2/2}dt.
$$
I just don't know where to start with this monster. I tried rewriting the second expression in the final expression but I don't know how to continue from:
$$
\Phi\left(\frac{-y-Ta}{\sqrt{T}}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\big(\frac{-y-Ta}{\sqrt{T}}\big)}e^{-t^2/2}dt
$$
Any help at all with this would be appreciated!!

Comment: Is your last formula (assuming you derived that) not exactly the final step? The integral defining $\Phi$ cannot be solved unless we are only interested in $\Phi(+\infty)$ or $\Phi(0)\,.$